# Como puede conectar a mysql con PDO ,

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo que realizar el crud en `mysql` pero la conexión debe ser necesario que sea  extendiendo del `pdo`, tengo una conexión pero no se si esta conectando, al tratar de hacer una consulta me salen errores;

Estos son los datos de la base de datos:

```
define('SERVIDOR',  'mysql');

define('HOST',      'localhost');
define('BD',        'HOD');
define('USER',      'root');
define('PASSWORD',  '');
define('PORT',      '5432');
define('CHARSET',   'UTF8');
```

Esta es la clase que crea la conexión en `postgres` funciona bien pero nunca la he trabajado en `mysql` extendiendo de `pdo`.

```
class BASE_DATOS extends PDO
{

    private $servidor = SERVIDOR;
    private $host     = HOST;
    private $port     = PORT;
    private $charset  = CHARSET;
    private $bd       = BD;
    private $user     = USER;
    private $password = PASSWORD;

    private $conexion;
    private $repetirconexion;
    private $errorconexion;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $opciones = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT       => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try {

            $conexion = parent::__construct(
                "$this->servidor:
                    host       =   $this->host     ;
                    port       =   $this->port     ;
                    dbname     =   $this->bd       ;  
                    user       =   $this->user     ;
                    password   =   $this->password ;
                "
            );
            parent::setAttribute($opciones);
            $this->repetir_conexion = true;
            $this->error_conexion   = "";
            $this->comprobar = "Conexion Exitosa";

            return $conexion;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error_conexion = 'Ha surgido un error y no se puede conectar a la base de datos. Detalle: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $this->comprobar = "Conexion Fallida !";
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function Probar_Conexion()
    {return $this->comprobar;}

    public function getRepetirConexion()
    {return $this->repetirconexion;}

    public function getErrorConexion()
    {return $this->errorconexion;}

}
```

Uso esta función normalmente trabajando en `postgre` pero en `mysql` no me funciona:

```
        function Trayecto () {
    
        $tabla            = "SELECT * FROM trayecto ORDER BY idtrayecto ASC";
        $respuestaArreglo = '';
        try { 
            $datos = BASE_DATOS::prepare($tabla);
            $datos->execute();
            $datos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $respuestaArreglo = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $respuestaArreglo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
    
            $errorReturn = ['estatus' => false];
            $errorReturn += ['info' => "error sql:{$e}"];
            return $errorReturn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona? Qué error te sale? Revisaste los logs de php? Por favor, **edita tu pregunta** y añade esta información. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Suele ocurrir que para usar PDO, particularmente cuando se usan mecanismos de autocarga de clases, **PDO no esté disponible directamente** y sea necesario crear una referencia explícita al principio del archivo en que se crean las conexiones. En este caso, antes de `class BASE_DATOS extends PDO` debes insertar la línea `use PDO;`

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla y rápida con la que puedes crear una conexión para luego poder llamarla en tu controlador en tus otras clases es de esta forma

```html
<?php

class Database
{
    //DB Parameters
    private $host = '127.0.0.1';
    private $dbName = 'dbname';
    private $username = 'postgres';
    private $password = 'password';
    private $conn;

    //DB connect method
    public function connect()
    {
        $this->conn = null;

        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            #echo "Connected";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error de Conexion :" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Luego la clases la creas de esta manera(No olvides llamar el  archivo de conexión).

```html
<?php

require_once './Config/Database.php';


class User
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }

}
```

Además al constructor le pasas una variable que será la de tu  conexión para que al momento de instanciarla lo puedas hacer de la siguiente forma:

```html
require 'Models/User.php';
$start = new Database();
$conn = $start->connect();

$user = new User($conn);
$resultUser = $user->getUser($userId);
$totalUser = $resultUser->rowCount();

foreach ($resultUser as $userb) {
    $userName = $userb['name'];
    $domainId = $userb['domain_id'];
    $senderId = $userb['sender_id'];
}
```

Esta es una forma sencilla y rápida, sin embargo hay infinidad de maneras de hacerlo, te aconsejo que leas la documentación de php para ello.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Comment: gracias por la ayuda , pero ese metodo lo conozco y funciona muy bien trabajo usando ese, pero la universidad me cambio la forma de trabajo , quieren  que usa base de datos mysql y que la conexion sea obligatoriamente extendiendo de PDO .

Comment: Es exactamente lo que estás viendo, es PDO.

Comment: Incluso todas las Query: SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE puedes colocarla dentro de un try catch para controlar los errores a través de la herramienta que suministra pdo, el ejemplo es con pgsql, solo tienes que cambiar pgsql por mysql y listo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class conectar extends PDO
{
   private $tipo_base='mysql';
   private $servidor='localhost';
   private $usuario='root';
   private $clave='tuclave';
   private $basedatos='tu_base_de_datos';
   public function __construct()
   {
    try {
        parent::__construct($this->tipo_base.':host='.$this->servidor.';dbname='.$this->basedatos, $this->usuario, $this->clave, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES  \'UTF8\''));

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'érror al conectar la base';
        exit;
    }

    // echo 'conectado';
}   
}
```

yo lo hago de esta manera, espero te ayude.

Comment: ¿Por qué un `parent::__construct` ? viene de otra clase?